# Next.js dynamic route error: The provided path `page-name` does not match the page: `/[slug]`

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am attempting to use `[slug].js` to render pages adjacent to `index.js` via `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths`. Upon navigation to a page using the dynamic route I get a mismatch error. This error occurs even when the provided path does in fact match the page slug and page props content.

When the `index.js` is duplicated and renamed to `page-name.js` (e.g. `about.js`) the page renders fine, so I believe the issue lies with how I am using `getStaticPaths`. In reality, I do not fully comprehend the relationship between `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths`. Is there some mapping which occurs to allow the engine to look up the appropriate props given whatever path in the map?

`Index.js`

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import { getPageDataBySlug } from '../lib/api';

export default function Page(pageData) {
  const page = pageData;
  return (
    <>
      <h1>document title is: {page.documentTitle}</h1>
      <Link href="/[slug]" as="/about">
        <a>
          <h5>Link to About</h5>
        </a>
      </Link>
    </>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const props = await getPageDataBySlug('home');
  return {
    props
  };
}
```

`[slug].js`

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import { getPageDataBySlug, getApiDataPaths } from '../lib/api';

export default function Page(pageData) {
  const page = pageData;

  return (
    <>
      <h1>document title is: {page.documentTitle}</h1>
      <Link href="/" as="/">
        <a>
          <h5>Link to Home</h5>
        </a>
      </Link>
    </>
  );
}

// Only grab the entry for this page
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const props = await getPageDataBySlug(params.slug);
  return {
    props
  };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const apiDataPaths = await getApiDataPaths();
  return {
    paths: apiDataPaths?.map(({ slug }) => `${slug}`) ?? [],
    fallback: false
  };
}
```

`getStaticProps` returns the correct page content

```
{
  "title": "About",
  "slug": "about",
  "description": "About page description",
  "documentTitle": "Pithy Compelling Headline",
  "article": {
    "content": [[Object], [Object]],
  }
}
```

`getApiDataPaths()` returns

```
[
  { slug: 'about' },
  { slug: 'another-page' },
  { slug: 'yet-another' }
]
```

And the `getStaticPaths()` map returns `paths` as an array:

```
[
  'about',
  'another-page',
  'yet-another'
]
```

What am I missing here? Should `getStaticPaths` only the path of the current page?

FWIW I am using Contentful as the API and that's working perfectly.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Next Js Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching?fbclid=IwAR1Mn-xnITNz6WHVKqoANGMJwA3rp1jhu_RUlfP7nDyn3Ml0Xxxmlr4mOd8#getstaticpaths-static-generation) Helped out in finding the error.
This is where you went wrong. You were passing in an array of objects in this format:

```
[{id:1}, {id:2}]
```

when the getStaticPaths was expecting this:

```
[
    { params: { id: '1' } },
    { params: { id: '2' } }
]
```

Solution:

```
  export async function getStaticPaths() {

  const apiDataPaths = await getApiDataPaths();
  // Empty arr to build new paths
  const newPaths = [];
  // Add params to every slug obj returned from api
  for (let slug of apiDataPaths) {
    newPaths.push({ params: { ...slug } });
  }
  // Return paths to render components
  return {
    paths: newPaths,
    fallback: true
  };
}
```

You can also consider cleaning the data on the serverside.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works as expected, although I still don't grok the relationship between getStaticPaths and getStaticProps… all in good time.

Comment: Man you are a living legend!

Answer (score 0):

```js
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {

    return {
        fallback: false,
        paths: [
            {
                params: {product_id: 'Car' }
            },
            {
                params: { product_id: 'Yoga' }
            },
            {
                params: { product_id: 'Nature' }
            },
            {
                params: { product_id: 'Beachs' }
            },
            {
                params: { product_id: 'Animals' }
            },
            {
                params: { product_id: 'Laptops' }
            },
        ],
    }
}


export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
    
    const prod_id = context.params.product_id;
    return {
        props: {
            product_id: prod_id,
        },
        revalidate: 10,
    };
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).